# php Encoding: Violation of encoding rules

Tags: php, soap

I have a PHP script that is doing a SOAP request to the server. PHP errors out with

```
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules
```

Initial instinct is there is an issue with my request. I took a network capture of the request and sent it to the web server via curl and it seems to have come back OK. The request that is sent by PHP soap and curl is the same which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/Integrics/Enswitch/API" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:download_music_file><username xsi:type="xsd:string">dovid</username><password xsi:type="xsd:string">passsowrd</password><music xsi:type="xsd:int">45</music><file xsi:type="xsd:int">1</file><checking xsi:type="xsd:int">0</checking></ns1:download_music_file></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><download_music_fileResponse xmlns="http://www.example.com/Integrics/Enswitch/API"><gensym><name xsi:type="xsd:string">music_45_1.wav</name><data xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary">BASE 64 REMOVED</data><mimetype xsi:type="xsd:string">audio/x-wav</mimetype></gensym></download_music_fileResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

The php code that does the quest is:

```
<?PHP

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$uid = 'dovid';
$pass = 'password';
$func = 'download_music_file';
$soap = new SoapClient("enswitch_3.9.wsdl", array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => false, 'keep_alive' => false, 'connection_timeout' => 15));
$result1 = $soap->$func($uid, $pass, 45, 1,0);

if(isset($soap->__soap_fault)){
echo 'There was an error connecting via SOAP. Below is the error:';
    print_r($soap->__soap_fault->faultstring);
    }
?>
```